# Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring

`Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'apistagefse.gateway.data.DTO.ValidationCreationDTO'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'apistagefse.gateway.data.DTO.ValidationCreationDTO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`

spring method

```
 public ResponseEntity<DocumentBaseResponse> validateAndCreate(@RequestParam(name = "requestBody") ValidationCreationDTO requestBody, @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please have a look at [TOUR] and [ASK]

Answer (score 0):

As per the error I am seeing I think that you are trying to take the payload using request param.

```
 validateAndCreate(@RequestParam(name = "requestBody") ValidationCreationDTO requestBody
```

Instead try to use following line.

```
 validateAndCreate(@RequestBody(name = "requestBody") ValidationCreationDTO requestBody
```

If this is not working then please try to provide more insight about the problem you are encountering.

Comment: sorry but this is not the solution i have used this have same error,  @RequestBody not have property name in spring 2.76